# Comparing files (text sources) in Orange

Tags: text-mining, orange

What is the best method to compare text files in Orange?
How do I find the difference or similar between two texts and relations between main nodes?

Answer (score 1):

The similarity hashing widget can compute document similarity within a certain corpus.

[image]